# Get all posts which was posted on X Days WordPress

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, get-posts

I want to get all post which was posted on X Days, I don't want 7 days old post or 1 Month old posts, Because it will return all posts which will be older 7 days or one month.
Like Today is 15 SEP, I want to get all posts which was post on 5 SEP. 
Only 5 sep not older then 5 SEP. Only one Day posts.
I have try code like this

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        'after' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-10 days')) 
    )
);
```

But its return 10 days old posts.
Any help to get post for X days?

Comment: I just need one date post. Like Only post which was posted on 1 SEP or which was posted on 25 Oct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use '[date_query'](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters) to achieve exactly what you need. All you have to do is not to use 'before' or 'after', but only date (the way WordPress does when you go to day archive).

Here’s the code you can use:

```
$date = strtotime('-10 days');

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => date('Y', $date),  
            'month' => date('m', $date),
            'day'   => date('d', $date),
        ),
    ),
);
$posts= new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
$y = date('Y');
$m = date('m');
$d  = date('d',strtotime("-7 days")); //Date you want

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'date_query' => array(
        array(
            'year'  => $y,  
            'month' => $m,
            'day'   => $d,
        ),
    ),
);
$posts= new WP_Query( $args ); //you will get posts which are posted on specific date
```

Comment: This will return all posts which is older then 7 days, Even it will return posts from 2015.

Comment: No, it will return posts from given day. There is another bug in that code - all dates have to be changed by 7 days. Otherwise it won’t work at first 7 days of month.

Comment: You can adjust date parameters